# How to include [ in xml element name

Tags: xml, encoding, svg

Is there any way to include the [ character in an xml element name?

For example

```
<AWSECommerceService.ItemSearch.ItemSearch.Request[0].SearchIndex>Electronics</AWSECommerceService.ItemSearch.ItemSearch.Request[0].SearchIndex>
```

The reason for using this is that in SVG hidden request input values are specified using xml elements whose name specifies the request key.

For example:

```
  <xforms:model id="form1">
<xforms:instance>
    <q>toyota</q>
    </xforms:instance>
<xforms:submission id="submit1" xforms:method="get" xforms:action="http://www.google.ca/search" />
```

would result in a request to http://www.google.ca/search?q=toyota

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't - it's not a valid part of an XML element name.

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#NT-Name):

> The ASCII symbols and punctuation
>   marks, along with a fairly large group
>   of Unicode symbol characters, are
>   excluded from names because they are
>   more useful as delimiters in contexts
>   where XML names are used outside XML
>   documents; providing this group gives
>   those contexts hard guarantees about
>   what cannot be part of an XML name.

There then follows BNF for what *is* allowed:

```
NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] 
                  | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D]
                  | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] 
                  | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] 
                  | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] 
                  | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF] 

NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 
                  | [#x0300-#x036F]  | [#x203F-#x2040]

Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*

Names         ::= Name (#x20 Name)*

Nmtoken       ::= (NameChar)+

Nmtokens      ::= Nmtoken (#x20 Nmtoken)*
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

That's a serious limitation of svg xforms then since you might need request parameters that have [ in their name and I couldn't find any other way to include hidden parameters in a request than by defining xforms elements (xml elements) that are not tied to a UI control

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. The [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name) defines an element name as being a `NameStartChar` followed by `NameChar`s and neither of those contain square brackets